Negating a sequence in SystemVerilog assertions
I have a reasonably basic SVA question, but I'm not sure what the trick is for getting somewhere. I'm trying to say that if A is true for 32 cycles, then B should become true at some point. Equivalently, I could say A && !B is not allowed to be true for 32 cycles.
Is there a way to encode this as a SystemVerilog assertion? I'm in an FPV context, so it  would also be really nice to avoid encoding "not xyz" as xyz |-> 0 (to avoid the tool reporting a hole in the coverage).

Well, that was easier than I feared! It turns out that you can negate properties with a not operator. So the example above turns into something like not ((A && !B) [*32]).
For the original context for the question, see OpenTitan PR #22528.
